# How to define what is the number of the elapsed timer?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<System.Timers.Timer> list = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
    List<Thread> ltread = new List<Thread>();
    Thread t1;
    System.Timers.Timer tick;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ltread[i]=new Thread(list[i].Start);
            ltread[i].Start();
        }
    }
    void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Stop();
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text += "I have ended\r\n";

        }));

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           tick = new System.Timers.Timer();
            tick.Interval = 3000;
            tick.Elapsed+=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
            ltread.Add(t1);
            list.Add(tick);

        }
    }
}
```

how can I get the number of the  elpased timer ?

Comment: Have you considered using Threading.Timer instead?  What were your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
int index = list.IndexOf(((System.Timers.Timer)sender));
```

Comment: well, when timer enters   OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
     i need to know what is the index of this timer)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `System.Timers.Timer` doesn't give you the ability to attach an arbitrary value that is passed to the `Elapsed` event handler. You can do that with  `System.Threading.Timer`, although it will require a little bit of modification to your code.

Your creation code would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    var tick = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, i, 3000, 3000);
    list.Add(tick);
}
```

The second parameter to the constructor is user-specific data that will be passed to the callback. In this case, I'm just telling it to pass the timer number.

Of course, your list will have to be `List<System.Threading.Timer>`.

The timer uses a callback method rather than an event. The callback looks like this:

```
void TimerTick(object state)
{
    int timerNumber = (int)state;
    list[timerNumber].Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite); // stops the timer.
}
```

If your timers will always fire only once and then stop, you can initialize them as one-shot rather than periodic. With `System.Timers.Timer`, just set the `AutoReset` property to `False`. With `System.Threading.Timer`, pass `Timeout.Infinite` as the last argument to the constructor. If you do that, then there's no reason to stop the timer in the event handler or callback method.